# Matlab syntax matrix bracket or no bracket

Tags: matlab, syntax

I notice that you can create a matrix using both of the following code in matlab...

```
m=[1:2:10]
```

or

```
m=1:2:10
```

Is there actually any difference between the two above?  they seem to output the same thing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference, the square brackets can be used to concatenate in for example:

```
m = [1:2:10 50]
```

results in:

```
m =

     1     3     5     7     9    50
```

For array used in your question there is no need to do so.